# How to reading OTP from firebase SMS automatically in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a code that asks for an OTP verification code to register the phone in firebase. It works fine manually but I want to make the code or app read the code sent in SMS from firebase and check it automatically.
For example, most applications when the verification code is requested and after the phone receives the verification code, the code is automatically written in the verification code registration boxes.

I searched for a long time, but it didn't work with me.

full code:

```
class _OtpScreenState extends State<OtpScreen> {
  String phoneNo;
  String smsOTP;
  String verificationId;
  String errorMessage = '';
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool showLoading = false;
  void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
    setState(() {
      showLoading = true;
    });

    try {
      final authCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

      setState(() {
        showLoading = false;
      });

      if (authCredential?.user != null) {


      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        showLoading = false;
      });
      print(e.message);
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(

                children: [


                  Container(

                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),

                    child: Column(

                      children: [

                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: PinEntryTextField(

                                fields: 6,
                                onSubmit: (text) {
                                  smsOTP = text as String;
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            verifyOtp();
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            height: 45,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color:     CustomColors.Background,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child:  Text('Check'),

                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Future<void> generateOtp(String contact) async {
    final PhoneCodeSent smsOTPSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]) {
      verificationId = verId;
    };
    try {
      await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: contact,
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verId) {
            verificationId = verId;
          },
          codeSent: smsOTPSent,
          timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
          verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {},
          verificationFailed: (exception) {
            print(exception);

          });
    } catch (e) {
      handleError(e as PlatformException);

    }
  }

  //Method for verify otp entered by user
  Future<void> verifyOtp() async {
    if (smsOTP == null || smsOTP == '') {
      print('please enter 6 digit otp');
      return;
    }
    try {

      final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationId,
        smsCode: smsOTP,
      );
      signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);

    } catch (e) {
      handleError(e as PlatformException);
    } }

  void handleError(PlatformException error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'ERROR_INVALID_VERIFICATION_CODE':
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        setState(() {
          errorMessage = 'Invalid Code';
        });
        print('error');
        break;
      default:
        print('error');
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: see the answer below, with Screenshot, I have posted there,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IOS, SMS autofill is provided by default.

For android you can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill).

Comment: Hello brother, thank you for your reply. Do we have to use this package? Can't we do that with the code itself?

Comment: Then you might have to write the code in Java or Kotlin to listen to the sms. This package simplifies these steps for you.

Comment: I don't think it works for firebase auth sms OTP.... because firebase doesn't allow us to customise the OTP message text

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your code:

```
String otpValue = credential.smsCode.toString();
```

Example from my code:

[image]

Comment: i've tried this, but it doesn't work at all

Comment: @muazharinalfan Can you please share the code?